# Valid JSONPath is throwing EOF in RestAssured JsonPath

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

The JSONPath that is normally working is not working when used in rest-assured-JSONPath

`tenants=jpath.getList("$..aa[?(@.name=='tid')].value");`

is throwing

```
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 59.
   untime-response'.$..aa[?(@.name=
```

`$..aa[?(@.name=='tid')].value` is working when I validated using https://jsonpath.com/

what am i doing incorrectly? please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath), the jsonpath library in rest-assured uses [Groovy GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) syntax and NOT [Jayway's jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) syntax which is what you're trying. If you post a sample json you're working with and what you're trying to extract, I can try to help you come up with the correct expression.